# WCF Service LINQ Query to signin a user

Tags: c#, wcf, linq, ienumerable

I'm stuck with a LINQ query to signin a user in my application. I want to check the SQL Azure table named `tbluser` and i'm using generated LINQ DataClasses to query my SQL azure table. I have successfully been able to query the LINQ table `tblAsset` to pass queries where either `*` or only one column is required.

I understand that to signin a user i'll need to check the username and password using `WHERE` but i haven't been able to crack this one.

i have tried the following code:

```
 public List<User> SigninUser(int uname, string pass)
{
    DataClasses1DataContext context = new DataClasses1DataContext();
    IEnumerable<User> result = (from a in context.Users
                  where (a.UserID==uname && a.Password==pass)
                  select new 
                  { 
                      a.UserID, 
                      a.Password
                  }).ToList()
                  ;
    return result.ToList();

}
```

but this returns an error -

`Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<AnonymousType#1>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<MyService.User>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create an anonymous type with:

```
new 
{ 
    a.UserID, 
    a.Password
}
```

But your result is of type: `IEnumerable<User>`.

Instead of `IEnumerable<User>` use:

```
 IEnumerable<User> result = (from a in context.Users
                      where (a.UserID==uname && a.Password==pass)
                      select a).ToList();
```

or even better:

```
 IEnumerable<User> result = context.Users.Where(a => a.UserID==uname && a.Password==pass);
```

(With thanks to justMe and Navik)

Comment: @JustMe: Correct. I try to change as less as possible to the orriginal code so that it is easier for the questioner to see what is different. Of course it is very tempting to refactor the code, than the questioner would not really know what went wrong and what could have been done better. That is why i stated my last 'observation'. And you just did another great one :)

Comment: @Navik: Yes you are right. The problem will be moved to the line where the results are returned. I'll update my answer.

Comment: `select a` wouldn't be sufficient as i need to check both username and password fields that will be checked when the user signs in to my client application that consumes the WCF Service.

Comment: and `select a` generates an error `not all code paths return a value`

Comment: oops, there's an error in my comment. It has to be: `IEnumerable<User> result = context.Users.Where(a => a.UserID==uname && a.Password==pass);`

Comment: using the one line code returns this error - `The name 'a' does not exist in the current context.`

Comment: Sorry, just saw your comment now, There aren't any errors now and it compiles. I'll let you know as soon as I check back with my client application.

Comment: Thanks! that works great! 
but i have an implementation question. I mean, how do i validate the credentials in my client app? I have a button that calls the query. Now how do i check if the query returns: 0 results or 1 result?

Comment: well, the whole method signature is a bit strange. I think it should be more like `bool SigninUser(int uname, string pass)`. And then query could be `bool result = context.Users.Any(a => a.UserID==uname && a.Password==pass);`

Comment: Hey i figured it out, i used `SigninUserCompletedEventArgs e` variable  to check `if (e.Result.Any()) // row was returned else // no user found.`